Spring boot - handle Oauth2 Authentication with JWT assertion
I have a Spring Boot application that currently handles Oauth2/OIDC authentication with a client secret. I need to replace this with a client_assertion and client_assertion_type to handle certifcate based authentication.
Here's what the API call looks like with a client secret:

And here's what it should like like with a call using client_assetion:

The details to be sent are configured in a Spring Boot OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails class, which is passed to an OAuth2RestTemplate via the constructor. That rest template is used make the call to retrieve the access token.
Here is how it constructs the OAuth2RestTemplate. Note the OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails are passed in the OAuth2RestTemplate constructor.
 @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ApLoginSettingsConstants.AUTH_PROVIDER, havingValue = ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID)
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails myPlatformOpenIdClient() throws ConfigurationException, InvalidAttributeValueException {
        ApLoginOpenIdSettings openIdSettings = apLoginSettingService.getOpenIdSettings();
        final AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

        String verifyUrl = openIdSettings.getVerifyURL();

        details.setClientId(openIdSettings.getClientId());
        details.setClientSecret(decryptionService.decryptTextUsingPlatformKeys(openIdSettings.getClientSecret()));
        details.setAccessTokenUri(openIdSettings.getTokenUrl());
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(openIdSettings.getAuthorizationUrl());
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList((openIdSettings.getScopes()).split(",")));
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(openIdSettings.getRedirectUrl()+ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID_AUTH_ENTRY);
        return details;
    }


   @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ApLoginSettingsConstants.AUTH_PROVIDER, havingValue = ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID)
    public OAuth2RestTemplate myPlatformOpenIdTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) throws ConfigurationException, InvalidAttributeValueException {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(myPlatformOpenIdClient(), clientContext); <==== OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails passed into the template constructor)
    }

The OAuth2RestTemplate is set as an attribute of a filter called OpenIdConnectFilter, which is created in the resource server configuration, and which handles authentication.
In the filter, the request for the access token is made like so:
    AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest = context.getAccessTokenRequest();

        context.getAccessTokenRequest().setPreservedState(settingService.getOpenIdSettings().getRedirectUrl()+ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID_AUTH_ENTRY);

        accessTokenRequest = context.getAccessTokenRequest();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        ((OAuth2RestTemplate) restTemplate).setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
        accessTokenData = accessToken;

I think all i need to do is create a class to replace the OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails which removes the client secret and adds the client_assertion (JWT token) and client_assertion_type (fixed string), as follows:
public class JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails extends BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails {
    private String clientAssertion;
    private String clientAssertionType;

public class JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails extends BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails { private String clientAssertion; private String clientAssertionType;

public JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
    setGrantType("client_credentials");
    setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
}

public String getClientAssertionType() {
    return clientAssertionType;
}

public void setClientAssertionType(String clientAssertionType) {
    this.clientAssertionType = clientAssertionType;
}

public String getClientAssertion() {
    return clientAssertion;
}

public void setClientAssertion(String clientAssertion) {
    this.clientAssertion = clientAssertion;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getRequestParameters() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("client_id", getClientId());
    parameters.put("scope", getScopeAsString());
    parameters.put("client_assertion_type", getClientAssertionType());
    parameters.put("client_assertion", getClientAssertion());
    parameters.put("grant_type", getGrantType());
    return parameters;
}
}

And pass it to the Oauth2Template in place of the current OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails.
Is this true? I've been looking for someplace where I could verify this.
